# The followingbunch of test is executing perfectly except the update test

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js, waterline

The following bunch of test is executing perfectly except the update test.

```
'describe.only('UsersModel', function() {

    describe('#create()', function() {

        it('should check create function', function (done) {
          var newUser = { firstname: "fname", email: "myemail@gmail.com"};
            User.create(newUser)
                .then(function(results) {
                // some tests
                done();
            })
                .catch(done);
        });

    });

    describe('#find()', function() {
        it('should check find function', function (done) {
            User.findAll()
                .then(function(results) {
                // some tests
                done();
            })
                .catch(done);
        });

    });

    describe('#update()', function() {

        it('should check update function', function (done) {
            User.update()
                .then(function(results) {
                // some tests
                done();
            })
                .catch(done);
        });
    });


    describe('#destroy()', function() {


        it('should check destroy function', function (done) {
            User.destroy()
                .then(function(results) {
                // some tests
                done();
            })
                .catch(done);
        });

    });

});
```

---

```
>  UsersModel
    #create()
      √ should check create function
    #find()
      1) should check find function
    #update()
      2) should check update function
    #destroy()
      √ should check destroy function


  2 passing (46s)
  2 failing
```

1. UsersModel #find() should check find function:
   `[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  Error: In Waterline >= 0.9, findAll() has been deprecated in favor of find().`

2. UsersModel #update() should check update function:
   `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
         at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:189:19)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you even read logs?

1) It says that `findAll()` has been deprecated in favor of `find()`. So you need to replace `findAll()` with `find()`.

```
it('Should check find function', function (done) {
  User
    .find()
    .then(function(results) {
      // some tests
      done();
    })
    .catch(done);
});
```

2) Next. It says that "timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test". What about to call `update()` with parameters but not just empty function? What is Waterline need to update? You need to specify what to update and etc...

```
it('Should check update function', function (done) {
  User
    .update('<USER_ID>', {key: value})
    .then(function(results) {
      // some tests
      done();
    })
    .catch(done);
});
```